# Matrix row alignment on two sides of an equation, with rules

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I have the following code to generate a matrix equation, on the LHS matrix, a couple of rules are added, that causes the RHS corresponding rows misaligned (vertically). How do I adjust subtle vspace in the RHS matrix if I'm sticking with the current code? Also is there a way to adjust the gray-scale of the rules (to make them less distracting)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% add vertical lines
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs} % add horizontal lines
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,matrix,positioning}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=3pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}[cc|c|c|c|c]
\phantom{abcd}      & \phantom{ }       &       &       & 0     & \phantom{abcd}  \\
      &       &       &       & 0     &  \\
      &       &       &       & \cdots     &  \\
      &       &       &       & \cdots     &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
      &       & a^{*}_{ts}     &       & 1     &  \\  \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
      &       &       &       & 0     &  \\
      &       &       &       & \cdots     &  \\
      &       &       &       & \cdots     &  \\
      &       &       &       & \cdots     &  \\
      &       &       &       & 0     &  \\
      &       &       &       & 0     &  \\  \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
      &       & \tikzmark{enter}{$c^{*}_s$}     &       & \tikzmark{leaving}{$c^{*}_t$}     &  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \phantom{four} \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
b^{*}_t \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
-v \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (enter) -- ++(0,-1cm) node [label={[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-20pt]entering}] {};
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (leaving) -- ++(0,-1cm) node[label={[xshift=8pt,yshift=-20pt]leaving}] {};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When you use `\midrule` vertical rules don't connect; why don't you use `\hline`?

Comment: @egreg hline leaves no space to the delimiters


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tz3qL.jpg

Comment: Yes, that's a small problem. You solve it by using `\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc|c|c|c|c@{}}` and `\end{array}\right]` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `array` is more flexible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,matrix,positioning}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=3pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{\qquad}|c|@{\quad}|c|@{\qquad}}
           & 0      \\
           & 0      \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\ \hline
a^{*}_{ts} & 1      \\ \hline
           & 0      \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\
           & 0      \\
           & 0      \\ \hline
\tikzmark{enter}{$c^{*}_s$} & \tikzmark{leaving}{$c^{*}_t$}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\\ \\ \\ \\
b^{*}_t \\
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
-v
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (enter) -- ++(0,-1cm) node [label={[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-20pt]entering}] {};
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (leaving) -- ++(0,-1cm) node[label={[xshift=8pt,yshift=-20pt]leaving}] {};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you load also `xcolor` and `colortbl`, you can change the tint of the rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,matrix,positioning}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=3pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\arrayrulecolor{black!30}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{\qquad}|c|@{\quad}|c|@{\qquad}}
           & 0      \\
           & 0      \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\ \hline
a^{*}_{ts} & 1      \\ \hline
           & 0      \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\
           & \cdots \\
           & 0      \\
           & 0      \\ \hline
\tikzmark{enter}{$c^{*}_s$} & \tikzmark{leaving}{$c^{*}_t$}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\\ \\ \\ \\
b^{*}_t \\
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
-v
\end{array}\right]
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (enter) -- ++(0,-1cm) node [label={[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-20pt]entering}] {};
  \draw[<-,>=stealth] (leaving) -- ++(0,-1cm) node[label={[xshift=8pt,yshift=-20pt]leaving}] {};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The color must be reestablished at the end, because `\arrayrulecolor` is a global declaration.

Comment: awesome! any way to pack the `\cdots` little tighter?

Comment: @JindanZhou `\newcommand{\pdots}{{\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot}}`