# How can I write description/text beside matrix as shown?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: The preferred method is to use \tikzmark.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183189/matrix-row-alignment-on-two-sides-of-an-equation-with-rules for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think it's more like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234906/101651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is probably a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234886/101651), but I like to show you an alternative solution with `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\newcommand{\mybrace}[3]{%
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] 
        ($(pic cs:#1)+(-.3,.3)$) -- node[xshift=-1em, align=left, text width=4em]{#3} ($(pic cs:#2)+(-.3,-.1)$);}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmark{lp} P \\
\tikzmark{lq} Q \\
\tikzmark{gp} P \\
\tikzmark{gq} Q \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
    \mybrace{lp}{lq}{Load}
    \mybrace{gp}{gq}{Gen}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]